# How to save pdf file to local using swift 5 in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I'm developing an iOS application using Swift 5 that will convert plain text to pdf format. And I want to share the pdf file with Whatsapp application, but I couldn't find how to save the pdf file before and then the url of the file I saved with Whatsapp. how can I do that?

Edit: I’m converting the plain text to pdf format I have pdf data in my hand and I want to save it to local and get the url of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

```
var interactionController: UIDocumentInteractionController!
```

And then via button (for example) you can open the controller.

```
@IBAction func savePDF(_ sender: Any) {      
     self.interactionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: "http://website.com/title.pdf")
     self.interactionController.delegate = self
     self.interactionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: button.frame, in: view, animated: true)
 }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
    let title = "PDF Title"

    guard let outputURL = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent(title).appendingPathExtension("pdf")
            else { fatalError("URL not created") } // PDF url

    pdfData.write(to: outputURL, atomically: true) // pdfData is your PDF file

    self.interactionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: outputURL)
    self.interactionController.delegate = self
    self.interactionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: button.frame, in: view, animated: true)
```

Comment: I understand that this code is to open the pdf file but I’m converting the plain text to pdf format I have pdf data in my hand and I want to save it to local and get the url of it

Comment: Check out the update at the top.